# How to return multiple checkbox names to the excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, checkbox

After creating a bunch of checkboxes in the form frame and creating an 'Ok' command button, what is the code to be able to send the checkbox names back to the spreadsheet into Column A row 22 and then continue downwards with each checkbox name.  For example, if I have checkbox names, (Green, Blue, Purple, Red) and the user checks Blue and Red and then clicks 'Ok'.  I want the spreadsheet to display "Blue" on cell A22 and then Red on cell A23.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop/iteration over the forms `.Controls` collection.  Since the collection may contain other types of controls (Listbox, option button, etc.) use simple `If/Then` logic to check the *type* of control before proceeding.

```
Sub Example()
Dim ctrl as control
Dim i as Integer

For each ctrl in Me.MyFrame.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        Range("A22").Offset(i).Value = ctrl.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```